Why does df contain several tmpfs entries?
I understand that df -a includes "pseudo, duplicate, and inaccessible file systems".  This results in quite a few mounts being hidden such as:
udev             8055632         0   8055632   0% /dev
devpts                 0         0         0    - /dev/pts

... which don't appear unless I pass the -a option.  However, I'm interested as to what's included when I don't pass -a:
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            1624300      3292   1621008   1% /run
/dev/sda1      122485360  12664524 103552780  11% /
tmpfs            8121496     60308   8061188   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1      460366888 154205092 282702932  36% /home
tmpfs            1624296      1688   1622608   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc2      488282108 324162964 164119144  67% /media/jez/Picard - Main [C]

The three "real" partitions from my perspective are sda1, sdb1, and sdc2 which point to actual partitions on physical disks.  How does df decide that its default output will also include some other mounts; apparently tmpfs ones?  Isn't tmpfs a "pseudo" file system?

tmpfs isn’t a pseudo file system, it’s a real file system that stores its contents in virtual memory. The difference is that pseudo file systems offer a representation of something else, whereas real file systems store artefacts directly.
Significantly for df, pseudo file systems can’t run out of storage in the usual way, because data can’t be added to them directly. Real file systems can run out of storage, and that’s what df really “cares about”. Since tmpfs file systems can fill up, they are listed by default.

(Working from GNU df because POSIX does not have the -a flag.) By default df will show mounted filesystems that have a non-zero size.
Example
df -ah

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.9G  5.6G  2.0G  74% /
devtmpfs        458M     0  458M   0% /dev
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
tmpfs           462M  1.1M  461M   1% /dev/shm
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           185M  1.5M  184M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
cgroup2            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup
systemd-1          -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
mqueue             0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
sunrpc             0     0     0    - /run/rpc_pipefs
debugfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
fusectl            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
configfs           0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
/dev/mmcblk0p1   63M   22M   42M  35% /boot
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
binfmt_misc        0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1001

The entries with a zero size (second column) will be omitted by default, i.e. these filesystems:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
proc               0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs              0     0     0    - /sys
devpts             0     0     0    - /dev/pts
cgroup2            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup
systemd-1          -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
mqueue             0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
sunrpc             0     0     0    - /run/rpc_pipefs
debugfs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs            0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
fusectl            0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
configfs           0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
ramfs              0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
binfmt_misc        0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc

leading to the default output shown here:
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.9G  5.6G  2.0G  74% /
devtmpfs        458M     0  458M   0% /dev
tmpfs           462M  1.1M  461M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           185M  1.5M  184M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1   63M   22M   42M  35% /boot
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1001

This is at odds with its documentation, both from info and man, which says ,

With no arguments, df reports the space used and available on all
currently mounted file systems (of all types)

but also

-a --all Include in the listing dummy, duplicate, or inaccessible file systems, which are omitted by default.

This is confirmed in the source code (coreutils, df.c). Here fsu_blocks is the number of filesystem blocks, show_all_fs is set by -a and show_listed_fs is set for filesystems explicitly listed on the command line:
if (fsu.fsu_blocks == 0 && !show_all_fs && !show_listed_fs)
  return;

